# Which part of a bitmap file is metadata?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have been modifying bitmap files, and I've been getting some very strange results. I think I may accidentally be changing part of the metadata. Which part is the metadata, so I know to leave it out of the binary manipulation I am doing?

I am looking for an answer that tells me which bytes are part of the metadata, whether they are at the beginning or end of the file. By metadata I mean anything that isn't part of a pixel.

Comment: When you say "bitmap files" are you speaking of the .bmp format or something else?

Comment: @MarkRansom `.bmp` files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Simple Breakdown

There are two kinds of Windows Bitmap file:

- DDB - Device Dependent Bitmap  ( Bitmap Version 1 )
- DIB - Device Independent Bitmap ( Bitmap Version 2-5 )

#### DDB

There are two parts to a DDB file:

- Header/Metadata
- Pixel Data

Detect a DDB file and Offset by:

- The first *WORD* = **0x0000**
- The offset for the Pixel Data is always = **10**

#### DIB

There are three parts to a DIB file:

- Headers/Metadata
- Data
- Color Profile ( Version 5 Only )

There are three parts to the Header/Metadata

- DIB File Info
- DIB Image Info
- Color Table

Detect a DIB file and Offset by:

- The first *WORD* = **0x4D42**
- The offset for the Pixel Data is stored in the *DWORD* at byte **10**
- The DIB version is based upon the header **size** located in the *DWORD* at byte **14**

  - Version 2 = **12**
  - Version 3 = **40**
  - Version 4 = **108**
  - Version 5 = **124**
- If the DIB is Version 5, check the DWORD at byte **116** to get the end of the Pixel Data/ offset of the Color Profile.

#### References

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183392.aspx
- http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/BMP
- http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 6):

Bytes 10 through 13 of a `.bmp` file contain a 4-byte integer which is the offset to the start of the pixel data. Everything before that offset in the file is metadata, and everything on or after that offset is pixel data or unused padding.

Comment: +1 but note that this is for DIB only and not DDB.  DDB the offset is always 10.  Also the pixel data can be followed by a color profile structure so everything from the offset to the end of the file is not always just pixel data.